# Configuring attachments for ArcGIS Local Government "Citizen Service Request" App

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-local-government

Has anybody configured the [Citizen Service Request](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b4756cb6d25e43b995c5fef887b1d5e8) app that ESRI's Local Government has developed? I have it ready to go, but can't get the attachments to work properly, either pics or documents. I can't find a space in the js code for the service to be specified either...

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the email you sent to our team alias about this issue as well.

The attachments should be enabled on the ServiceRequest feature class and then the application will pick them up.

You do not need to reference any location in the JS or config.js for the attachments to work, the app will automatically detect them.

-Lindsay

Comment: thanks for the help. to the best of my knowledge, the attachments are enabled (tables are included as relates back to the ServiceRequest FC). Still not working and I also get the cannot attach because the file is greater than 5mb message.